# Align points with grouped bars

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to make a make shift lollipop chart using two separate chart types, a bar and a point. The problem is they when the bar is grouped the points don't align, like so:

[image]

Expectation:
[image]

Is it even possible to have them align?

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

hc <- highchart()

hc <- hc %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(pointWidth = 2)) 

hc <- hc_colors(hc, colors = c("#ffb078", "#ffc600"))

# example data
d <- tibble(x = rep("Apple", 2), y = c(87, 94), g = c("a", "b"))

# add line
hc <- hc %>% hc_add_series(data = d, "bar", hcaes(x = "x", y = "y", group = "g"), dataLabels = list(x = 5, enabled = TRUE))

# add point
hc <- hc %>% hc_add_series(data = d, "point", hcaes(x = "x", y = "y", group = "g"), marker = list(enabled = TRUE, symbol = "circle", radius = 4), showInLegend = FALSE)


hc
```

**Side note** - *Why I'm not using the lollipop chart type:*

There is a chart type in [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/lollipop) which does exactly this but I think it is a very recent addition and it is not present in the `highcharter` wrapper for R?! (yet, I guess).

Comment: I managed to align them using `hcaes(x = c(-.15, .15))` for the points.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the lollipop series has been added to Highcharts in v8.0.0, but Highcharter uses v7.2.0. You can ask Highcharter's author to create a branch with dumbbell.js and lollipop.js modules so you can use them in the current Highcharter version. I did the same here: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/567
This is the best way to make it work in R now.